# Use rolle's theorem to conclude $f(c)=f''(c)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a < b$ be two real numbers, and let $f : [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(a) = f(b)$ and $f'(a) = 0$. By applying Rolle’s theorem to the auxiliary function $h(x) = e^{−x}((f(x) + f'(x))$, show that
there exists a number $c \in (a, b)$ such that: $f''(c) = f(c)$.

Ive been staring at this problem for hours and I can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider the necessary conditions in the hypothesis of Rolle's theorem and try to find ways to satisfy those conditions (for $h(x)$). Then you have $h'(c) = 0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$. Compute $h'(x)$ and you are done.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding x and y such that h(x)=h(y) in order to apply rolle's theorem. I know x and y must satisfy f'(x)=-f(x) and f'(y)=-f(y) so I'm thinking they should involve exponentials...